# View [auth.login] not found yet view is in the auth folder

Tags: laravel, github, heroku, laravel-8

I am have a laravel app that has been working, but today when I connected my laravel app to github via Heroku it gives the

```
View [auth.login] not found error. 


if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) { 
       return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);    
        }   

     }      
  return $next($request);  
  }}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show us the file structure of your view folder. Do you have a login.blade.php in an auth sub folder of views?

Comment: Yes, login.blade.php is inside the auth folder. In localhost it is working fine